# Why are non-SVG elements with a "url()" SVG filter applied appearing glitchy in Safari?

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-filters

I am trying to apply an feDisplacementMap in an SVG to images (the problem also persists on any DOM elements). It works exactly as expected in Chrome but turning up very strange and unpredictable results in Safari.

I tried moving the image as a linked element inside an SVG and using filter="url(#example)" instead of defining it in the CSS and that works as expected in Safari (and Chrome). I could not find anything regarding Safari not supporting filter: url(#example) anywhere and from all I can gather, it should work the same as it does in Chrome.

Here's a fiddle with the two versions: https://jsfiddle.net/85bnkLwt/

First version (which works in Chrome and seems like it should work in Safari):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter-warp" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.008" result="displacement-map" numOctaves="2" seed="1"></feTurbulence>
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="displacement-map" scale="100" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="image-wrap" style="filter: url(#filter-warp);">
  <img width="600" height="500" src="https://picsum.photos/600/500" alt="" />
</div>
```

Second version (which works in Chrome and Safari):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter-warp-2" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.008" result="displacement-map" numOctaves="2" seed="1"></feTurbulence>
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="displacement-map" scale="100" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/600/500" alt="" filter="url(#filter-warp-2)"/>
</svg>
```

For me (Mac, Chrome Version 75 and Safari Version 11.1.2) the two images look very similar in Chrome (as expected) and in Safari, the image outside the SVG with the filter applied is totally glitched out. It seems like they should both work the same and I am unable to find any resources or documentation that says why the CSS filter would not work in Safari. All other filters work as expected.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Safari only supports applying SVG filters to SVG elements, not to HTML elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok thank you. That's frustrating. Is there documentation or a source for that? Even when looking for that specifically, I'm not finding anything official. The only other reference I found was another unsourced Stack Overflow comment. The MDN Web Docs imply that it is supported in Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility Filter: url() is even included in one of the examples. Caniuse does not mention this limitation either. It seems like if it is not supported that should be included in documentation, no?

Comment: MDN is a collaborative effort, feel free to join in and update it. That [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) is about CSS filters rather than SVG filters though.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok got it. Thank you. I wouldn't feel confident about editing MDN since I'm still pretty in the dark on the support / if there are plans for support, etc. It's not that it does nothing, it's that it almost works but looks super strange. Also, to clarify, I am talking about CSS filters. Using an SVG filter as the value of a CSS filter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#SVG_filter Right?

Comment: Nope, a CSS filter looks like filter: blur(7px); An SVG filter is filter: url() where url points to some SVG filter element.

Comment: @RobertLongson OP asked for a source for your comment, and you replied saying to update the MDN page to reflect the details of your comment